# Windows 11 desktop icons are stacked on top of each other. How to restore them to their original positions?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, icons, desktop, window-manager

I don't know what exactly happened, but my desktop on Windows 11 doesn't show the icons anymore. It only displays the Recycle bin and, for some reason, when it is selected the shaded region is now a horizontal line (this shaded region indicates icon selection and usually is just a square shaded region around the icon).

[image: part of my desktop showing the recycle bin and shaded region indicating selection]

There are other icons of text files in my desktop, but they are not visible on the Desktop. Only when I go into explorer and see what's on the Desktop:

[image: explorer Desktop folder with text files]

When I changed the relative positions of my two monitors in system settings, I see that the icons appear to be all sitting on top of each other. Even when I have only my notebook monitor, the problem persists.
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? When I switch to another Windows user, I don't have this problem.

Comment: Apparently some Win11 bug can cause this. Here's a possible fix: https://www.beaming.co.uk/knowledge-base/stacked-desktop-icons/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Desktop Icons Spaced Out?](https://superuser.com/questions/1554668/desktop-icons-spaced-out)

Comment: @Ramhound no. They are stacked, not spaced out.

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo - Did you try the solution described in the potential duplicate?

Comment: You really should test that. My link has a solution for the exact same issue you're experiencing, and it happens to be exact same solution presented in @Ramhound's link.

Comment: I managed to get to trying it today. Posted the answer. Because the question is slightly different, I believe we should keep it. I will edit the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue.

This link provided the solution: http://www.beaming.co.uk/knowledge-base/stacked-desktop-icons/

Which is the same solution to a slightly different problem (icons spaced out, instead of stacked) that has already been posted in a different question: [Desktop Icons Spaced Out?](https://superuser.com/questions/1554668/desktop-icons-spaced-out)

Here is the quote of that answer:

> **DISCLAIMER: Take caution when using Registry Editor.**
>
> - Change the `IconSpacing` and `IconVerticalSpacing` values in Registry Editor to the Windows default value of `-1128`:
>
> 1. Open Registry Editor by hitting Win + R and typing `regedit` into the Run box.
> 2. Hit Enter and click 'Yes' to open Registry Editor.
> 3. Navigate to following:
>
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
>    <sup>You can paste this in the "address bar" in registry editor >window</sup>
> 4. Change `IconSpacing` and `IconVerticalSpacing` values to `-1125` by double->clicking on them and modifying the current value.
> 5. Save changes and exit Registry Editor.
> 6. Reboot your machine.

Thanks to @Ramhound and @Peregrino69 for pointing me towards these resources.

Comment: +1 for referencing the other thread :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to run an elevated command prompt and run this command ?

```
sfc /scannow
```

This should trying to "repare windows bugs"...
On an other side, it should simply be a bug about whitch you can send a report to microsoft.

Comment: As usual, no luck: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."